# c++ Floodfill algorithm final errors

Tags: c++, algorithm, flood-fill

My floodfilling algorithm is nearly finished, but there is a small error somewhere, I've spent about 3 hours debugging, but i can't seem to find it!

note:
 When reading in I use numbers from 0 to 15 to define the walls

1 = top
2 = right
4 = bottom
8 = left
(so 13 would mean that the top/bottom/left walls are there)

My Program:

- It reads in number of fields to calculate the biggest room from (so everything below here is a cycle that gets repeated for the number of fields).
- Then it gets the room's dimensions
- Now in the class field, it creates an array of objects (Cell) which store the walls around (left right down up), and a value below 16
- Now here is where I think the problem comes, reading in values through std::cin
- and then when everything is read in, it scans for empty (0), and then creates a room, and checks for availeble spaces around it (using the wall-check)
- and at the end it returns the max value, and we are done.

The input I use:

```
1
2 2
13 3
15 14
```

so what happens is is that somewhere, in or the wall-check, or the creation of a object Cell something goes wrong (I think)

Here is my script, and sorry to have to ask something silly like this!

Thanks in advance

```
    // een simpele floodfill

    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <bitset>


class Cell {

    private:
      int  kamer, value;
      bool left, right, up, down;

    public:            
      // constructor
      Cell::Cell() {};
      // functions
      bool CanLeft()      { return left ; }
      bool CanRight()     { return right; }
      bool CanDown()      { return down ; }
      bool CanUp()        { return up   ; }
      int  GetRoom()       { return kamer; }
      void SetRoom(int x)  { kamer = x   ; }      
      void SetValue(int x, int room=0) { value  = x;
                             kamer = room;
                             std::bitset<sizeof(int)> bits(value); 
                             if (bits[3]) left  = true;
                             else         left  = false;
                             if (bits[2]) down  = true;
                             else         down  = false;
                             if (bits[1]) right = true;
                             else         right = false;
                             if (bits[0]) up    = true;
                             else         up    = false;
                           }
};

class Field {

    private:
      int Biggest_Chamber;
      int Y;
      int X;
      int temp;
      Cell playfield[][1];

    public:
      // constructor
      Field::Field(int SizeY, int SizeX) {
                    Y = SizeY;
                    X = SizeX;
                    Cell playfield[SizeY-1][SizeX-1];
                    }
      // Create a 2d array and fill it

      void Get_input() {

           for (int Yas = 0; Yas < Y; Yas++){

               for (int Xas = 0; Xas < X; Xas++){

                   std::cin >> temp;
                   playfield[Yas][Xas].SetValue(temp);         
               }
           } 
      };  
      void Start() { Mark(0,0,1); }

      void Mark(int y, int x, int nr) {
                  std::cout << nr;
                  temp = nr;
                  playfield[y][x].SetRoom(nr);
                  if (playfield[y][x].CanLeft())   {
                     if (playfield[y][x-1].GetRoom() != 0) {
                                                    Mark(y, x-1, nr);
                                                    std::cout << nr;
                                                    system("pause");}}
                  if (playfield[y][x].CanDown()) {
                     if (playfield[y+1][x].GetRoom() != 0) {
                                                    Mark(y+1, x, nr);
                                                    std::cout << nr;
                                                    system("pause");}}
                  if (playfield[y][x].CanRight())  {
                     if (playfield[y][x+1].GetRoom() != 0) {
                                                    Mark(y, x+1, nr);
                                                    std::cout << nr;
                                                    system("pause");}}
                  if (playfield[y][x].CanUp())   {
                     if (playfield[y-1][x].GetRoom() != 0) {
                                                    Mark(y-1, x, nr);
                                                    std::cout << nr;
                                                    system("pause");}} 
                  for (int vertical = 0; vertical < Y; vertical++) {
                      for (int horizontal = 0; horizontal < X; horizontal++) {
                          if (playfield[vertical][horizontal].GetRoom() == 0) Mark(vertical, horizontal, nr+1);                   
                      }      
                  }
      }         
      int MaxValue() {
          int counter[temp];
          int max = 0;

          for (int y = 0; y < Y; y++) {
              for (int x = 0; x < X; x++) {
                  counter[playfield[y][x].GetRoom()]++;
              }
          }

          for (int i = 0; i < temp; i++)
          {
              if (counter[i] > max)
                 max = counter[i];
          }

          return max;
     }            
};


    int main() {
    using namespace std;


    int NrKamers;
    int sizeY;
    int sizeX;

    std::cin >> NrKamers;
    for (int i = 0; i < NrKamers; i++){

        std::cin >> sizeY >> sizeX;

        Field floodfield(sizeY, sizeX);
        floodfield.Get_input();
        floodfield.Start();

        std::cout << floodfield.MaxValue() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error message ? `class Field` already has a closing brace ( `};` ). Is it a typo that you are doing the same again ?

Comment: segmentation fault - but through debugging i found out that in somehow runs into an infinite loop at Markeer(int, int, int), what? the `;` behind it?

Comment: Translating your variable names and comments to English before posting would be polite; not everyone here understands Dutch.

Comment: To me it sounds as you are still confused about input-output issues. Try to divide your problem into two parts - one that reads input and just prints how it is (to test if you are reading correctly) and another that takes a hand-crafted puzzle directly (without reding input) and tries to solve it.

Comment: @missingno Thanks for that tip! you were right, i seperated the data and the algorithm and i found out that there were many more mistakes made! golden tip :)

Answer (score 1):

I have not had much time to deal with the code, but my first impression is that you are not marking (or rather not using the mark) each visited position in the array, so that you move in one direction, and while processing that other position you return back to the original square. Consider that the sequence of tests where: left, right, up, down; and that you start in the top-left corner:

You cannot move left, but you can move right. At that second recursion level you can move left and go back to square one. Then you cannot move left, but you can move right, so you go back to square two, from which you move to square one... infinitedly.

Before you move to the next square you have to mark your square as visited, and also check that the square you intend to move to has not been visited in the current run.

The segmentation fault is the result of infinite recursion, after you exhaust the stack.

Comment: That could be, but in my semantics i have covered that, uhm, in the `playfield[y][x].setNr(nr)` i change the room status of that cell from 0 to nr, and then whenever i want to go do a different cell, i check if it's roomstatus == 0,

but it could very well be that the syntax says different..

Comment: It is really hard to follow as it is, you might want to consider providing the whole code somewhere else (ideone?), I am not seeing the `setNr` method anywhere. If you refer to `setRoom(nr)`, that is modifying the internal `kamer` attribute, but that attribute is not used to control the recursion

Answer (score 0):

1-11-2017: NEW-VERSION; SUCCESFULLY TESTED WITH TWO BITMAPS.

I propose my C version of the Flood-Fill algorithm, which doesn't uses recursive calls, but only a queue of the offsets of the new points, it works on the window: WinnOffs-(WinDimX,WinDimY) of the double-buffer: *VBuffer (copy of the screen or image) and, optionally, it write a mask of the flood-fill's result (*ExtraVBuff). 
ExtraVBuff must be filled it with 0 before the call (if you don't need a mask you may set ExtraVBuff= NULL); using it after call you can do gradient floodfill or other painting effects. NewFloodFill works with 32 Bit per Pixel and it is a C function. I've reinvented this algorithm in 1991 (I wrote his in Pascal), but now it works in C with 32 Bit per Pixel; also not uses any functions calls, does only a division after each "pop" from queue, and never overflows the queue, that, if it is sized in the right way (about 1/4 of the pixels of the image), it allows always to fill correctly any area; I show before the c-function (FFILL.C), after the test program (TEST.C):

```
#define IMAGE_WIDTH 1024
#define IMAGE_HEIGHT 768
#define IMAGE_SIZE IMAGE_WIDTH*IMAGE_HEIGHT
#define QUEUE_MAX IMAGE_SIZE/4

typedef int T_Queue[QUEUE_MAX];
typedef int T_Image[IMAGE_SIZE];

void NewFloodFill(int X,
                  int Y,
                  int Color,
                  int BuffDimX,
                  int WinOffS,
                  int WinDimX,
                  int WinDimY,
                  T_Image VBuffer,
                  T_Image ExtraVBuff,
                  T_Queue MyQueue)

/* Replaces all pixels adjacent to the first pixel and equal to this;   */
/* if ExtraVBuff == NULL writes to *VBuffer (eg BUFFER of 786432 Pixel),*/
/* otherwise prepare a mask by writing on *ExtraVBuff (such BUFFER must */
/* always have the same size as *VBuffer (it must be initialized to 0)).*/

/*         X,Y: Point coordinates' of origin of the flood-fill.         */
/*     WinOffS: Writing start offset on *VBuffer and *ExtraVBuff.       */
/*    BuffDimX: Width, in number of Pixel (int), of each buffer.        */
/*     WinDimX: Width, in number of Pixel (int), of the window.         */
/*       Color: New color that replace all_Pixel == origin's_point.     */
/*     WinDimY: Height, in number of Pixel (int), of the window.        */
/*     VBuffer: Pointer to the primary buffer.                          */
/*  ExtraVBuff: Pointer to the mask buffer (can be = NULL).             */
/*     MyQueue: Pointer to the queue, containing the new-points' offsets*/

{
 int VBuffCurrOffs=WinOffS+X+Y*BuffDimX;
 int PixelIn=VBuffer[VBuffCurrOffs];
 int QueuePnt=0;
 int *TempAddr=((ExtraVBuff) ? ExtraVBuff : VBuffer);
 int TempOffs1;
 int TempX1;
 int TempX2;
 char FLAG;

 if (0<=X && X<WinDimX && 0<=Y && Y<WinDimY) do
  {
   /* Fill to left the current line */
   TempX2=X;
   while (X>=0 && PixelIn==VBuffer[VBuffCurrOffs])
    {
     TempAddr[VBuffCurrOffs--]=Color;
     --X;
    }
   TempOffs1=VBuffCurrOffs+1;
   TempX1=X+1;

   /* Fill to right the current line */
   VBuffCurrOffs+=TempX2-X;
   X=TempX2;
   while (X+1<WinDimX && PixelIn==VBuffer[VBuffCurrOffs+1])
    {
     ++X;
     TempAddr[++VBuffCurrOffs]=Color;
    }
   TempX2=X;

   /* Backward scan of the previous line; puts new points offset in Queue[] */
   if (Y>0)
    {
     FLAG=1;
     VBuffCurrOffs-=BuffDimX;
     while (X-->=TempX1)
      {
       if (PixelIn!=VBuffer[VBuffCurrOffs] ||
           ExtraVBuff && Color==ExtraVBuff[VBuffCurrOffs])
        FLAG=1;
       else
       if (FLAG)
        {
         FLAG=0;
         if (QueuePnt<QUEUE_MAX)
          MyQueue[QueuePnt++]=VBuffCurrOffs;
        } 
       --VBuffCurrOffs;
      }
    }

   /* Forward scan of the next line; puts new points offset in Queue[] */
   if (Y<WinDimY-1)
    {
     FLAG=1;
     VBuffCurrOffs=TempOffs1+BuffDimX;
     X=TempX1;
     while (X++<=TempX2)
      {
       if (PixelIn!=VBuffer[VBuffCurrOffs] ||
           ExtraVBuff && Color==ExtraVBuff[VBuffCurrOffs])
        FLAG=1;
       else
       if (FLAG)
        {
         FLAG=0;
         if (QueuePnt<QUEUE_MAX)
          MyQueue[QueuePnt++]=VBuffCurrOffs;
        }
       ++VBuffCurrOffs;
      }
    }

   /* Gets a new point offset from Queue[] */ 
   if (--QueuePnt>=0)
    {
     VBuffCurrOffs=MyQueue[QueuePnt];
     TempOffs1=VBuffCurrOffs-WinOffS;
     X=TempOffs1%BuffDimX;
     Y=TempOffs1/BuffDimX;
    }

  /* Repeat the main cycle until the Queue[] is not empty */
  } while (QueuePnt>=0);
}
```

Here there is the test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include "ffill.c"

#define RED_COL 0xFFFF0000
#define WIN_LEFT 52
#define WIN_TOP 48
#define WIN_WIDTH 920
#define WIN_HEIGHT 672
#define START_LEFT 0
#define START_TOP 671

#define BMP_HEADER_SIZE 54

typedef char T_Image_Header[BMP_HEADER_SIZE];
void main(void)
{

 T_Image_Header bmpheader;
 T_Image *image;
 T_Image *mask;
 T_Queue *MyQueue;

 FILE *stream;
 char *filename1="ffill1.bmp";
 char *filename2="ffill2.bmp";
 char *filename3="ffill3.bmp";
 int bwritten;
 int bread;

 image=malloc(sizeof(*image));
 mask=malloc(sizeof(*mask));
 MyQueue=malloc(sizeof(*MyQueue));

 stream=fopen(filename1,"rb");
 bread=fread(&bmpheader, 1, BMP_HEADER_SIZE, stream);
 bread=fread((char *)image, 1, IMAGE_SIZE<<2, stream);
 fclose(stream);

 memset(mask,0,IMAGE_SIZE<<2);

 NewFloodFill(START_LEFT,
              START_TOP,
              RED_COL,
              IMAGE_WIDTH,
              IMAGE_WIDTH*WIN_TOP+WIN_LEFT,
              WIN_WIDTH,
              WIN_HEIGHT,
              *image,
              NULL,
              *MyQueue);

 stream=fopen(filename2,"wb+");
 bwritten=fwrite(&bmpheader, 1, BMP_HEADER_SIZE, stream);
 bwritten=fwrite((char *)image, 1, IMAGE_SIZE<<2, stream);
 fclose(stream);

 stream=fopen(filename3,"wb+");
 bwritten=fwrite(&bmpheader, 1, BMP_HEADER_SIZE, stream);
 bwritten=fwrite((char *)mask, 1, IMAGE_SIZE<<2, stream);
 fclose(stream);

 free(MyQueue);
 free(mask);
 free(image);
}
```

I've used, for the input of the test program shown, the follow Windows uncompressed .BMP image (ffill1.bmp):

[image]

Filled, by the test program shown, as follows (ffill2.bmp):

[image]

Using "mask" instead of NULL, the output bitmap is (ffill3.bmp):

[image]